# lucene query filter not working

Tags: lucene, auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

I am using this `filter hook` in my **[Auth0 Delegated Administration Extension](https://github.com/auth0-extensions/auth0-delegated-administration-extension)**.

```
function(ctx, callback) {
  // Get the company from the current user's metadata.
  var company = ctx.request.user.app_metadata && ctx.request.user.app_metadata.company;
  if (!company || !company.length) {
    return callback(new Error('The current user is not part of any company.'));
  }

  // The GREEN company can see all users.
  if (company === 'GREEN') {
    return callback();
  }
  // Return the lucene query.
  return callback(null, 'app_metadata.company:"' + company + '"');
}
```

When user logged in whose company is `GREEN` can see all users. But when user logged in whose company is `RED` can't see any users whose company is `RED`.

I need to make this when user logged in, user should only be able to access users within his company. (except users from GREEN company).

But above code is not giving expected result. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with this solution.

Used search functionality to filter users. I had to change below two files.

`fetchUsers` function in `client\actions\user.js`

changed

> export function fetchUsers(search = '', reset = false, page = 0)

to

> export function fetchUsers(search = '@red.com', reset = false,
>   page = 0)

AND

`onReset` function in `client\containers\Users\Users.jsx`

changed

> onReset = () => {   this.props.fetchUsers('', true); }

to

> onReset = () => {   this.props.fetchUsers('@red.com', true); }

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to a little warning note on the [User Search documentation page](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/user-search)

Basically they don't let you search for properties in the `app_metadata` field anymore. Unfortunately, this change was breaking and unannounced.

We had to make changes to our API so that we keep a copy of the `app_metadata`s in a separate database and convert lucene syntax to MongoDB queries, so that we can query by a chain of `user_id:"<>" OR user_id:"<>" OR ...`.

One caveat though, you can't pass a query that's longer than 72 `user_id`s long. This number is so far undocumented and obtained empirically.

Also, you can't rely on Auth0's hooks to add new users to your database, as these don't fire for social logins, only for `Username-Password-Authentication` connections.

I hope this gave you some explanation as for why it wasn't working as well as a possible solution.
If I were you, I would look for an alternative for Auth0, which is what we are currently doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This helped me a lot.